# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'XXX'; column does not allow nulls

Tags: sql-server, django

I have the below model:

```
class Loan(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
```

When I try to save **date** and **description** I get the above error

[image]

below is my **admin.py** file:

```
@admin.register(Loan)
class LoanAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      pass
```

and below is my table created through migrations:

[image]

Django 3.2.6.
How can I solve this?

SQL Server version is **Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8-GDR)**

I tried :

```
class Loan(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: I think you have not migrated after some changes to your models.py. So, do: `python manage.py makemigrations` Then: `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I did and i have three fields in the database.

Comment: You don't have to specify the id field if you are working with django models. it will automatically add that field.

Comment: Is this a legacy database?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU8-GDR) (KB4583459) - 15.0.4083.2 (X64) 
 Nov  2 2020 18:35:09 
 **Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0 <X64> (Build 19041: ) (Hypervisor)**

Comment: I mean was the table created through django? Can you try to delete all the tables and run the migration again?

Comment: This worked I deleted the table and re-run the migrations

Comment: Cool! Glad you aren't stuck anymore

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked to this problem was to delete all migrations and create new migrations.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add id column specifically. Django creates id column itself.

```
class Loan(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
```

This should work.
Also, if you want to add custom id column check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109940/custom-id-field-in-django-model)

Comment: I started from this code and it is not working too